# How to add button to every node by default using TreeItem in React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, button, parent-child, react-typescript

I am working with parent-child tree in react typescript using react mui library 'TreeItem' and 'TreeView' and I don't know how to add button to each and every node by default.

And I have done an parent-child dropdown as shown in the below image. And I want an button to each and every node as I marked with blue and red color.

[image]

Here is My code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TreeView from "@mui/lab/TreeView";
import TreeItem from "@mui/lab/TreeItem";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

interface FileNode {
  id: string;
  parentId: number;
  name: string;
  children?: readonly FileNode[];
}

export const TreeViewFile = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<FileNode[]>([]);
  const [selectedNode, setSelectedNode] = useState({});
  const [selectedRoot, setSelectedRoot] = useState({});
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null as any);
  const [dropDownData, setDropDownData] = useState([] as any);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://localhost:44306/api/user/Getlistofchildren")
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
    console.log("selectedNode", selectedNode);
    console.log("selectedRoo", selectedRoot);
  }, [selectedNode, selectedRoot]);

  const handleChange = (event: any, nodeId: string) => {
    data.forEach((treeRoot: any) => {
      if (treeRoot.id === nodeId) {
        setSelectedRoot(treeRoot);
        setSelectedNode(treeRoot);
        return;
      }

      handleSelectedNode(treeRoot.children, treeRoot, nodeId);
    });
  };

  const handleSelectedNode = (
    children: string | any[],
    treeRoot: React.SetStateAction<{}>,
    nodeId: any
  ) => {
    if (!children) {
      return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      let childNode = children[i];
      if (childNode.id === nodeId) {
        setSelectedRoot(treeRoot);
        setSelectedNode(childNode);
        return;
      }

      handleSelectedNode(childNode.children || [], treeRoot, nodeId);
    }
  };

  const displayTreeView = (treeViewArray: any[]) => {
    if (!treeViewArray) {
      return null;
    }
    return treeViewArray.map(
      (treeViewItem: {
        children: any[];
        id: React.Key | null | undefined;
        name:
          | string
          | number
          | boolean
          | React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>
          | React.ReactFragment
          | React.ReactPortal
          | null
          | undefined;
        childNodes: any;
      }) => {
        return (
          <TreeItem
            key={treeViewItem.id}
            nodeId={`${treeViewItem.id}`}
            label={treeViewItem.name}
          >
           
            {displayTreeView(treeViewItem.children) }
          </TreeItem>
        );
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TreeView
        onNodeSelect={handleChange}
        sx={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 800, overflowY: "auto" }}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      >
        <div>
          {displayTreeView(data)}
        </div>
      </TreeView>
    </>
  );
};
```